# Renaming files starting with particular chars to a particular name in AIX

Tags: shell, unix, rename, aix

I have multiple files which are starting with error_* and i want to  rename all of those with a particular name. I am using the below script to do that but it is not working.

```
counter=1
for i in `ls error*`
do
  mv $i ABC$counter_$i
  $(( counter++ ))
done
```

Sample files which I want to rename

```
error_CO_5010wgs837in.10   
error_CO_coprofo.7
```

I want to use counter values while renaming each of the file, if i don't use counter it works fine. But i want to know why the above script doesn't work.here is the output which my script is giving:

```
ABCerror_CO_5010wgs837in.10
ABCerror_CO_coprofo.7
```

The output which i am expecting is as below:

```
ABC1_error_CO_5010wgs837in.10
ABC2_error_CO_coprofo.7
```

Comment: `$(( counter++ ))`: `dollar` is not needed.

Comment: Yeah tried without dollar also but not expected result.

Comment: maybe your `shell` doesn't support `((VAR++))` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$counter_` and this looks for the variable `counter_`. To specify that `counter` is the variable and you also want a `_`, use `${counter}_`.

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

# to avoid error* match exactly error* if does not expand to any result
shopt -s nullglob

counter=1
for i in error*
do
        echo "mv $i ABC${counter}_$i" #now it is echo; change to mv once you tested it works
        counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

See different ways to increment a variable: [How to increment a variable in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/a/385532/143251).